# How can I show/hide tab or navigation buttons of chrome by extension command?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am using chrome 47.0.2526.106 m (64-bit) on Win7 .

When I open a window by `window.open()` from JavaScript command, the popup style window opens.

That window does not have tab, bookmark bar nor navigation buttons . It has an address bar only. 
Then I mouse click upper left corner of the title bar, the pull down menu is opened.

In the menu, there is an item "show as tab" and I executed it.
Then the popup window became chrome normal window style that has tab, bookmark bar and navigation buttons.

My question is, how can I do this style change by chrome extension API commands? I looked around `chrome.windows` or `chrome.tabs` APIs, but I could not find the command.

Comment: [chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows)

Comment: So you want to make the window a tab and part of another window?

Comment: I want to make the popup window to have a tab but do not want to make it to be in part of another window.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the answer on the documentation page of `chrome.windows`...

Use the function [`chrome.windows.create`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#method-create). You can specify a configuration object as parameter to define how the new windows will be displayed.

For your, it will be something like :

```
chrome.windows.create({
    url : "http://url.com/foo",
    type : "normal"
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
My question is slightly different from your answer.
I want to do style change bidirectionally.
　
case1 [popup window with address bar] <--> [normal window with tab]
　
The open.window() function can create a popup window with address bar only.
The chrome.windows.create() with "popup" option creates a popup window WITHOUT address bar.
I can do the following style change by chrome.windows.update function.
　
case2 [popup window WITHOUT address bar] <--> [normal window with tab]
　
But, I want to do case1.